# Devexpress ActiveBandedGridView selected row?

Tags: c#, devexpress

In this method, I need to write additional condition when if the row is not selected only then make back color thistle. How can I do it?

```
private void docsActiveBandedGridView_CustomDrawCell(object sender, DevExpress.XtraGrid.Views.Base.RowCellCustomDrawEventArgs e)
{        
    DataRow dtrow = docsActiveBandedGridView.GetDataRow(e.RowHandle);

    if (dtrow != null && executeDocIDs.Contains(decimal.Parse(dtrow["ID"].ToString())))
         e.Appearance.BackColor = Color.Thistle;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

you can implement your own row style using the [GridView.RowCellStyle](https://documentation.devexpress.com/#windowsforms/DevExpressXtraGridViewsGridGridView_RowCellStyletopic) event.

```
private void docsActiveBandedGridView_RowCellStyle(object sender, RowCellStyleEventArgs e)
{
    //If row is selected or focused then do nothing   
     if(view.IsRowSelected(e.RowHandle) || view.FocusedRowHandle == e.RowHandle)
         return;   
     DataRow dtrow = docsActiveBandedGridView.GetDataRow(e.RowHandle);

     if (dtrow != null && executeDocIDs.Contains(decimal.Parse(dtrow["ID"].ToString())))
        e.Appearance.BackColor = Color.Thistle;
 }
```

To prevent selected or focused row to be painted in your existing code just check for the selected or focused row and do not forget to set `e.Handled= true` :

```
private void docsActiveBandedGridView_CustomDrawCell(object sender, DevExpress.XtraGrid.Views.Base.RowCellCustomDrawEventArgs e)
{  
    //If row is selected or focused then do nothing   
    if(view.IsRowSelected(e.RowHandle) || view.FocusedRowHandle == e.RowHandle)
      return;   
    DataRow dtrow = docsActiveBandedGridView.GetDataRow(e.RowHandle);

    if (dtrow != null && executeDocIDs.Contains(decimal.Parse(dtrow["ID"].ToString())))
         e.Appearance.BackColor = Color.Thistle;
    e.Handled = true;  //Do not forget to set Handled property to true to know the grid that you handled painting of the grid cell

}
```

**References:**
[How to customize the FocusedRow and SelectedRow appearance in the GridView](https://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Question/Details/T562028/how-to-customize-the-focusedrow-and-selectedrow-appearance-in-the-gridview)
[GridView Color Selected Rows](https://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Question/Details/T183335/gridview-color-selected-rows)
[Focused Row Appearance](https://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Question/Details/CQ2566/focused-row-appearance)

Answer (score 0):

This should tell you if the row is selected or not:

```
docsActiveBandedGridView.GetSelectedRows().Contains(e.RowHandle)
```

If you don't have multi-select enabled (`docsActiveBandedGridView.OptionsSelection.MultiSelect = false`), then it might actually be better to used the focused row handle, knowing there will never be more than a single row highlighted:

```
docsActiveBandedGridView.FocusedRowHandle == e.RowHandle
```